# How to trigger Github workflows on 'link Issue to PR'?

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like a workflow to trigger on an Issue once it is linked to a PR but it doesn't seem like this option is provided by [github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#available-events). Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this question yesterday and decided to refactor a solution that has been implemented in one of my projects, and came up with a GitHub Action for this: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/validate-issues-over-pull-requests

You can create a new workflow with the following content:

```yaml
name: PR has a valid Issue?

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: [ edited, synchronize, opened, reopened ]

jobs:
  checker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Issue Validator
        uses: HarshCasper/validate-issues-over-pull-requests@v0.1.1
        id: validator
        with:
          prbody: ${{ github.event.pull_request.body }}
          prurl: ${{ github.event.pull_request.url }}
```

Based on the `steps.validator.outputs.valid` value (which can be either `1` when an issue is linked or `0` when an issue will not be linked), you can trigger a workflow of your choice.

Right now, it will work if the PR author has explicitly mentioned `Fixes #XYZ` or `Resolves #XYZ` in the PR body. Explicitly linking an issue to a Pull Request is not supported as of now.

If you wish some action to be made on an Issue, like labeling, you can use the GitHub's CLI `gh` utility for this purpose. If there is any specific feature you would like to have, I would be happy to work on it!

Comment: Hats off to you for making this action. Although it would be most ideal for it to read when the issue is connected to the pr without writing in the pr body, this works well. Thank you.

Comment: How can I take this `0` or `1` in a conditional and use it in a following job action?

Comment: Hi @IanSteffy, I have added a sample workflow here: https://github.com/HarshCasper/validate-issues-over-pull-requests#example-workflow

Comment: I will try to add a feature where PRs linked with issues can also be validated (without putting `fixes #xyz` or `resolve #xyz`, and also retrieve the issue number which can be labeled.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific trigger to achieve it but it should be doable by combining the event triggers.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ edited, labeled ]
    branches:    
      - main
  issue:
    types:
      - opened
      - labeled
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this action triggers when an issue is connected to repository and not when the issue is linked to a PR